# php json format

Tags: php, json, jquery-post

I have a json response in this [url](http://knowyourdj.staging.techliance.com/webservices?action=GetSoundCloud&UID=1), which I have to validate from this [site](http://jsonformat.com/#jsondataurllabel).

I have stuck my head through many solutions,and I don't know what's wrong here.

I am very thankful for any help suggestions.

this is the code

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$obj=array();
$UID=isset($_REQUEST['UID'])?$_REQUEST['UID']:'';
if($UID!='')
{
    $sound_cloud=getLatestSound($UID);
    if($sound_cloud==false)
    {
        $sound_cloud['status']="No Record Found";
        $obj['status']="No Record Found";   
    }
    else
    {
        $sound_cloud['status']="successfull";           
    }
}
else
{
    $sound_cloud['errors']="required UID";
}

print stripslashes(json_encode($sound_cloud));
exit;
```

Comment: its giving a response { "status" : "Error Getting Data from URL" },
and 200 ok error in jquery post,
in simple browser it returns valid json

Comment: i copied that its valid,but still this is a webservice i am developing and it has to be retrieved from jquery or any other language,this site http://jsonformat.com/#jsondataurllabel is a standard url json validation,so i am not ok to go until i get valid json response via url

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$json = '{"stream_url":"http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/74950626/stream?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28","title":"Klaypex-Jump","status":"successfull"}';
$arrayval = json_decode($json);
print_r($arrayval);

// OR

$url = 'http://knowyourdj.staging.techliance.com/webservices?action=GetSoundCloud&UID=1';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$arrayval = json_decode($json);
print_r($arrayval);
?>
```

Result:

```
stdClass Object ( [stream_url] => http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/74950626/stream?client_id=b45b1aa10f1ac2941910a7f0d10f8e28 [title] => Klaypex-Jump [status] => successfull )
```

Comment: thanks but the first one gave {'status':'Error making your JSON pretty'}

Comment: you are right @dino it works for php,but what if it is in jquery post or get

Comment: jQuery.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
timeout: 10000,
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://knowyourdj.staging.techliance.com/webservices?action=GetSoundCloud&UID=1",
                dataType: "json",
                sucess:function(data, err){
    
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

Answer (score 0):

use

```
               $json = file_get_contents('http://knowyourdj.staging.techliance.com/webservices?action=GetSoundCloud&UID=1');//fetch contents from server
               $json = json_decode($json); // parse fetched contents
               if(!empty($josn)){
                          print_r($json);
               }else{
echo 'no result were found';
                }

             //lets find what we had parse
```

Comment: i am encoding the data from http://knowyourdj.staging.techliance.com/webservices?action=GetSoundCloud&UID=1

Answer (score 0):

echo it, not print. just try~

```
print stripslashes(json_encode($sound_cloud));

=>

echo  stripslashes(json_encode($sound_cloud));
```

------------------ edit

If this isn't a solution, I think this is a kind of same origin policy problem.

double check your url, it should have same domain with web page server.

[refrence - same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

use jquery jsonp,

Answer (score 0):

You can make an ajax call with jquery to your php like this

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:'/example.php', //your url
   data:{'seguros':a, 'esp':esp,'cont':cont}, //your variables 
   success: function(data){
      //handle your answer here
   }
});
```